# Multistore: change default store got admin inaccessible

Tags: magento2, admin, multistore, redirection

I have a magento website with multi store installation, i have a problem that the store domain.com redirects to default.com, the default.com is the default store domain, this is the 1st issue.

The second issue, when i tried to change the default store to domain.com, i got a loop redirection and the admin still loading and i no longer can access it. 
Edit: i fixed the 2nd issue in the table store_website i changed the is_default field to 1 for the default.com website

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to set store links according to Your store as

```
Backend > Stores > Setting > Configuration > Go to General Tab > Web > Base URLs
```

For Default Config you need to set one URL, for Another Store you need to set another URL. You do not use USE SYSTEM VALUE`.

You have also set some other setting as `Session Validation Setting Set to NO`.

Also you need to set `No` to `Single-Store Mode` under `General Setting`.

Comment: For Base URLs, they are unique for each store and they are correct.
How to configue Session Validation Setting Set to NO.
and Single-Store Mode?

Comment: Session Validation Setting is below the Base URL and Single- Store Mode is in Just upper side of web Tab.

Comment: I checked them, they are all to NO

Comment: Then you need to check in DB, how much entry you get of default.com